# Url Rewriting a dynamic wordpress page with parameters

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I am struggling a bit with how to rewrite a WordPress URL.

I have two custom post types that I gave these url structures:

```
mysite.com/erika-mustermann/
mysite.com/offer/shoe-repair/?bername=Erika-Mustermann&angname=shoe-repair&id=2177
```

The goal is to have the shoe-repair URL like this:

```
mysite.com/erika-mustermann/shoe-repair
```

My Problem is that there is not only /erika-mustermann/ but several other urls like /peter-parker/. But there is only one page with /shoe-repair/ (they only differ through the page parameters I've added in the template). I don't want to make a new shoe repair page for every name, I just want custom links like:

```
mysite.com/erika-mustermann/shoe-repair
mysite.com/peter-parker/shoe-repair
```

I tried several rewrite rules but I don't get anywhere. Here I thought that would rewrite the offer-page to mysite.com/offer/shoe-repair/erika-mustermann or mysite.com/offer/shoe-repair/peter-parker. But that doesn't work and only leads to an archive page

```
add_rewrite_rule( 
    '^offer/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?bername=$matches[2]',
    'top'
  );

add_filter('query_vars', 'foo_my_query_vars');
function foo_my_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = 'bername';
   
    return $vars;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 '^offer/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
```

Why do you have a question mark here at the end, that doesn't do anything here.

You also need to add_rewrite_tag otherwise it will never work.

Comment: Thank you I'll check it out. That makes sense!